# Template/Data/Model context for an empty list ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I've created a view for adding/removing items for a list. I'm trying to handle adding/removing dynamically, but I'm unclear on how to get the proper template context when the list is empty.

The view is based on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Service.Cms.ListItems;

namespace Bcp.Service.Cms.Documents
{
    public class Tasting //: Document
    {
        public Tasting() { }

        public List<DocumentListItem> relatedCrap { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Related List Item looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Service.Cms.ListItems
{
    public class DocumentListItem
    {
        public DocumentListItem() { }

        public Int32 documentId { get; set; }

        public String title { get; set; }

        public String documentType { get; set; }

        public String status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In order to save the list items, each of the properties will need to be prefixed with `tastingInfo.relatedDocs.#PROPERTYNAME#`
but if the list is empty when I load the view, I don't know how to access that context. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a Display Template for `List<DocumentListItem>` called DocumentListDisplay  containing the following:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%: ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix %>" />
```

I just call this template in my View before calling `EditorFor()` on the same model. It's kludgey, but it provides the template context without having to hard code anything or add anything to ViewData.